# How to add up cells when the numbers are in text form?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a column that displays the quantity of items but it is displayed in text form. So the first row is "5.0M" in the cell. I cannot convert it to 5,000,000 if I change the number format. Same for the other cells in the column. I was wondering if there was a way to convert 5.0M to 5,000,000 even though it's text form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*1000000
```

[image]

**Edit:**

To add thousands and billions use:

```
=IF(N(A1),A1,LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*10^(INDEX({3,6,9},MATCH(1,--(RIGHT(A1,1)={"K","M","B"}),0))))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! How would you add numbers that are in the thousands in formula if they're in the same column? And numbers less than 1,000 to just be ignored? And billions if that's possible?

Comment: @Arbie do the numbers always come in the form xB for billions, xM for millions, and xK for thousands? If so, you can use the idea basic outlined together with an ```IF``` statement. For example, ```=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="B", LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)-1)*1000000000, IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="M", LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)-1)*1000000, IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="K", LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)-1)*1000, "")))```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A4, "M"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4, "\d+.\d+|\d+")*1000000, )))
```

[image]

---

### update

```
=INDEX(SUM(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A4&"", "M"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4, "\d+.\d+|\d+")*1000000, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A4&"", "k"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4, "\d+.\d+|\d+")*1000,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A4&"", "B"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4, "\d+.\d+|\d+")*1000000000, A1:A4)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting way to go about it! Is it possible to add numbers in the thousands like "24k" or "1.3K" and numbers in the billions?

Comment: Shouldn't the numbers add up to 505,140,007?